# Can't configure routing Yii?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

Forgive me for such a frequent situation, I searched the Internet. I tried it, I didn't have anything goes. I can't configure routing in Yii. I would be grateful if anybody can help a beginner:

1) I have a finished project to Yii.

2) I have the cloud to digitalocean, installed the LAMP, in the/var/www/html uploaded project.

3) My /var/www/html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

4) /var/www/protected/config/main.php

```
// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        //not show index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ),
```

5) /var/www/html/protected/.htaccess

```
deny from all
```

6) Yii framework in /var/www/yii.

If you enter the URL of the project via a browser, enter /var/www/html/, /var/www/yii/does not see, is this normal?
Tell me how to configure the correct routing? (without "/?r=").
Folders 777, Files 666
rewrite_module (shared)

Comment: What do you mean by enter /var/www/html/, /var/www/yii/ does not see ?

Comment: From the browser when I enter the URL I get only the folder/var/www/html/, for example if I enter the valid http://123.456.2.3/yii/requirements/index.php there I will not be able to access from a browser, only html folder.

Comment: Your protected folder code is not accessible through browser because of .htacccess settings `deny from all`. This is expected settings as Apache should directly access protected folder but only through index.php. Same for Yii core library code which also not accessible through browser.

Comment: I deleted the .htaccess inside a folder /var/www/protected. Nothing has been changed. I can go http://123.123.12.12/?r=site/contact, but http://123.123.12.12/site/contact shows 404 error

Comment: Maybe I move/var/www/yii to/var/www/html? And configure the index.php?

Comment: Oh brother, then you should have simply write down this problem in first place instead of so much information.

Comment: Chances are you have apache rewrite module is not enabled.

Comment: apache2ctl -M rewrite_module(shared)

Comment: Moved the/var/www/html/yii directory also Yii situation, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would suggest to change your .htaccess file  from (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/427/htaccess-seo-friendly-url/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Now if you have not set virtual host and application is in some folder like /var/www/html/MySite. Then change RewriteBase in .htaccess to `RewriteBase /MySite`

Comment: Changed as you have, unfortunately, I do not have any effect.